# Align div content

Tags: html, css

I know there a many of these about but for some reason I keep failing to implement them.

So I need the content in the class `.infobox` to be in the middle of the `div`. So I need it aligned vertical and horizontally.

I have put **ALL** my code below as some of the "fixes" I tried worked but caused the layout to move and so on. So hopefully you guys can get it aligned without causing the layout to break.

Fiddle is at the bottom. On a side note if you have any tips on how to neaten the layout code please do let me know. But the main problem is aligning the content.

### HTML:

```html
<div id="con">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="header"><h1>Test</h1></div>
        <div id="left">
            <div class="infobox">Test: <br /> <input /> </div>
            <div class="infobox">Test: <br /> <input /> </div>
            <div class="infobox">Test: <br /> <input /> </div>
            <div class="infobox">Test: <br /> <input /> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="resultbox">
                  <ul>
                      <li>Test <br />Test</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="contactbox">
                <ul>
                    <li>Phone Number: <br /> 00000 000000</li>
                    <li>Email: <br /> test@Test.com</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```css
div {
    outline: 1px solid #000;
}
#box {
    width: 580px;
    height: 300px;
}
#header {
    height: 15%;
    background: url(http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/mechanik/mechanik1112/mechanik111200003/11665900-vector-cartoon-semi-truck.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size:80px 40px;
    background-position:right top;
}

#left {
    width:70%;
    height: 85%;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width:30%;
    height: 85%;
    float: right;
}
.infobox {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.resultbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.contactbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.contactbox ul, .resultbox ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.contactbox li, .resultbox li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/c82DU/1/)

**What I have tried:**

Tried to use `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` - This seemed to not align it correctly and then I couldn't get the layout to sit correctly.

Also looked into using `position: relative` and `position: absolute` but I have never been too good with them and couldn't manage to get the content to sit where I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of manipulating you mark-up a bit and added an extra `div` to achieve the output.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/L2AaC/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="cent">Test:
        <br />
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.infobox > .cent {
    outline: 1px solid #0F0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:20%;
}
```

**Whats happening here???** : since your content div `infobox` has the styling, to give a different set of styling to inner content(which is not floating), you **have** to use a them under a `child div` for display!

Comment: Apart from the fact you had a random `</span>` in there seems to work. I will have a little play with it and if all is well +1 and correct!

Comment: i was working on that `<span>` to work it out initially....dint worked though.....my bad for not omitting it...updated the link!! :)

Answer (score 0):

add `margin:0 auto;` to `#box`

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/c82DU/2/

Comment: No no no, you misunderstand. I don't want to center the whole thing, that's easy. I want the content within the div `.infobox` to sit in the middle of the div. E.g: equal height-top-bottom & equal width- left - right. Have I not made that clear in my question? If not let me know and I will try reword it.

Comment: ooh sorry, I understand now. I will take another look

Comment: It may have been just me skimming through the question, not the way you worded it.

Answer (score -2):

You could take a look at this site, it explains a bit about tables.

The layout u are using looks like a table, so why not use tables? easier text aligning
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Tables limited what you can do, I mean it is a possible solution but not for me. Tables are more for displaying information more then anything.

Comment: tables are not recommended...various `display` methods can be used instead!